Как в Steam проверить наличие достижения в другой игре?
Есть две версии игры в Steam:

демо-версия;
релизная версия.

Игроки проходят демо и зарабатывают достижения. В демо-версии игры есть достижения, которых нет в релизной версии.
Так можно проверить достижение в текущей версии игры:
Steamworks.SteamUserStats.GetAchievement(KEY, out bool achievement_completed);

Но этот метод обращается только к достижениям текущей версии игры.
Возможно ли в релизной версии игры узнать было ли получено достижение в демо-версии или нет? Может существует версия этого метода, которая принимает appId демо-версии игры?
